# Can not find symbol variable

Tags: android

before 1 hour in my project i got error saying: cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_MOVIE.

I have already try to clean project, rebuild, restart cache and all those things.

Still getting error, does anybody have idea what is happening.
This is my github: https://github.com/adnxy/MyMovieApp

Bellow are two activities that are having error:

MoviesAdapter Class:

```
public  class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivity.MovieViewHolder> {


private List<Movie> mMovieList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context mContext;

public MoviesAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MainActivity.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_movie, parent, false);

    final MainActivity.MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MainActivity.MovieViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, mMovieList.get(position));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

//Ispod koristimo Picasso za slike
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = mMovieList.get(position);
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(movie.getPoster())
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mMovieList == null) ? 0 : mMovieList.size();
}

public void setMovieList(List<Movie> movieList) {
    this.mMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.mMovieList.addAll(movieList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    //sve u adapter paket


}
```

MovieDetailActivity bellow:

```
public class MovieDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Movie mMovie;
private Reviews mReviews;
private Genres mGenres;
//private MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter rAdapter;
ImageView backdrop;
ImageView poster;
TextView title;
TextView description;
TextView releaseDate;
TextView voteAverage;
ListView genres;
ListView reviews;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE)) {
        mMovie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Detail activity must receive a movie parcelable");
    }


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    toolbarLayout.setTitle(mMovie.getTitle());


    backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
    description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_description);
    releaseDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_date);
    voteAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
    //genres = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genresArray);
    reviews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reviewArray);


    title.setText(mMovie.getTitle());
    description.setText(mMovie.getDescription());
    voteAverage.setText(mMovie.getVoteAverage());
    releaseDate.setText(mMovie.getReleaseDate());

    //nameReview.setList(mGenres.getName());


    poster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
    String internetUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(mMovie.getPoster())
            .override(800, 890)
            .into(poster);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(mMovie.getBackdrop())
            .into(backdrop);
}
```

Gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.mtin.mtin"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compile time error is pointing out that you don't have any member called `EXTRA_MOVIE`. Accordingly to the code you posted, (`MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE`) is a `public final static` member of `MovieDetailActivity`. Add

```
public static final String EXTRA_MOVIE = "EXTRA_MOVIE";
```

to `MovieDetailActivity`